# change convolution function if signal is above threshold?

Tags: filters, convolution

Let's say I have a signal $s(t)$ and two filters $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$, I also have a threshold $A$.

Now I define $a_1(t)$ as $a_1(t) = \min(s(t),A)$, then I do the convolution of $a_1* f_1$.

Now I also define $a_2(t)$ as $a_2(t) = \max(0, s(t)-A)$, (ie. whatever is above $A$) then I do the convolution of $a_2*f_2$.

The total result $a$ is $a=a_1*f_1+a_2*f_2$.

**Is there a name for such a kind of filter?**

Basically, I do some convolution filter on some part of the input, and some other convolution on the remaining part of the input, then add the results

This can also by generalized with more than 2 filters, or continuous thresholds and continuously parametrized convolution functions

Comment: Can you please clarify what a1 and s1 are in equations, by editing your question? Thanks!

Comment: Well, when adding $a=a_1+a_2$ this exactly yields $s(t)$. I suppose you want to add $a=f_1*a_1 + f_2*a_2$, dont you?

Comment: I can't think of any signal / problem where this is overly useful, since your thresholding operation introduces new frequencies into your signal. It feels like you're asking for something that solves a problem that you think solves your actual problem... this might be a case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info); I think you should add background to your question to explain what you're doing.

Comment: @lezebulon fixed that

Comment: @MarcusMüller for instance, I have a signal such that if it's too above a threshold, I want to integrate what's above over a longer period (so in that case the support of f2 is longer than the support of f1). This allows me to smooth differently my input depending on its value

Comment: @lezebulon believe it or not, I heavily doubt the operation you're describing is a good idea! Why do you want to do the integration? What's the purpose? Also, convolution with an $f$ is not an integration!

Comment: @MarcusMüller basically I want to smooth my input signal... if my signal is small enough I don't need to smooth it over a long period. However if it's above a threshold I want to smooth it on a longer period.

Comment: @lezebulon but that's different from what you're doing! You're introducing hard breaks at every threshold crossing. That will definitely wreck whatever you're doing if what you want is smoothness. And, I'm getting a bit tired of this, but: **Why** do you want to apply this selective smoothing? It's an unusual operation... repeat my last comment about XY Problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller how what I explained is different from what's I'm doing? 
basically my input is a sum of random amount that are arriving at each "t". So sometimes my s(t) will randomly be huge, in that case I want to smooth over time what I deem is too important above a "normal" level. But when it's not huge (normal level), I also want to be more reactive so I don't want to filter this over a long period of time

Comment: @lezebulon the problem is that that won't work – there's two cases: a) both filters have linear phase==constant group delay, and the same length, and I really fail to see where the advantage of having two different filters is (and you refuse to explain, so really, I'm going to assume there is none). Or b) they don't have linear phase and identical length, but then the output signal $a$ will have a complete discontinuity and be anything but smooth. So your approach really doesn't make sufficient sense, until you define what you *think* you'd use it for.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a name for such a kind of filter?

No. (Ok, there probably is, but it's not commonly used)

The point is that your filter is not a linear system, and thus has properties that make it unsuitable for most applications. Hence, I'd neither heard of someone using it, nor of someone giving it a name.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the *computing capacity* to run the two convolution algorithms in **parallel** side by side, you can **fade** between the two **outputs** based on the threshold $A$. You can even specify the *speed* and *curve* of the fading beside the threshold if you want.

This technique is often used for applications where you have to deal with parameter changes in the algorithms with minimalized transients in the output signals.